# Recursion gcd python

Tags: python

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if b==0:
       return a
    else:
       return gcd(b,a%b)
```

When I try to print the output of gcd with any 2 numbers I get the error "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting". Any idea ?

Comment: Try printing the types of `b` and `a` before calling `gcd` for the first time

Comment: Are you taking in user input to pass to this function?

Comment: You are not calling the function with integer numbers at all, but with strings. If this is in a program where you are getting the numbers by using the `input()` function, wrap  input's call in a call to `int`. For example: `value = int(input("type the first number: "))`

Comment: I think @jsbueno is right about your error; in the future, you should include all of your code (or enough to fully reproduce the problem), including the code that calls this function, where the parameters to this function come from, and where you print the result.

Comment: Yes I was calling it with strings, thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Python input error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286034/simple-python-input-error)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're calling the function with integers. Try casting to int.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function with integers. What you are doing is calling it with strings. If you are using `input`, cast the string with `int()`.